# Intersection between text files

Tags: python, bash, text, emacs, grep

How can I compute the intersection between two text files in terms of raw text? It doesn't matter whether the solution uses a shell command or is expressed in Python, Elisp, or other common scripting languages.

I know `comm` and `grep -Fxv -f file1 file2`. Both assume that I am interested in the intersection of *lines*, whereas I am interested in the intersection of *characters* (with a minimum on the number of characters necessary to count as a match).

Bonus points for efficiency.

**Example**

If file 1 contains

```
foo bar baz-fee
```

and file 2 contains

```
fee foo bar-faa
```

then I would like to see

- `foo bar`
- `fee`

assuming a minimum match length of 3.

Comment: So you’re going by words? Or every substring of length ≥ 3 that occurs in both files? (I don’t know of a general unix tool; you’d probably have to do some dynamic programming.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for Python's `difflib` module (in the standard library), and in particular `difflib.SequenceMatcher`.

Comment: and this is why I like this website. I learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 2):

okay here is a very simple python scripit to accomplish this

it can be imporved upon, but should do the job.

**temp.txt**

> xx yy xyz zz aa
>  xx yy xyz zz
>   aa
>  xx yy xyz zz aa
>  xx yy 111
>   aa cc

**temp2.txt**

> yy aa cc dd
>  ff xx ee 11
>  oo mm
>   aa tt

**common.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

def main():
    f1,f2 = tryOpen(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
    commonWords(f1,f2)
    f1.close()
    f2.close()

def tryOpen(fn1,fn2):
    try:
      f1 = open(fn1, 'r')
      f2 = open(fn2, 'r')
      return f1,f2
    except Exception as e:
      print('Oh No! => %s' %e)
      sys.exit(2) #Unix programs generally use 2 for 
                  #command line syntax errors
                  # and 1 for all other kind of errors.

def commonWords(f1,f2):

    words = []
    for line in f1:
      for word in line.strip().split():
            words.append(word)
    for line in f2:
        for word in line.strip().split():
            if word in words: print 'common word found => %s' % word    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

```
./common.py temp.txt temp2.txt
common word found => yy
common word found => aa
common word found => cc
common word found => xx
common word found => aa
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try messing around with the options to diff:  http://ss64.com/bash/diff.html

I'm still not clear on exactly what you are asking for though.  What constitutes a word in your definition?  And how is this intersection process defined here?

Comment: Any sequence of characters counts as a word. Sequences of characters that occur in both files are part of the intersection set. For example, with minimum match length of 1, all letters that are used in both files are part of the intersection set (and longer common sequences as well, if they exist).